# How to call viewHelper via OPT

Tags: php, zend-framework

I work with Zend Framework 1.12 and Open Power Template.
In ZF I made view helper `InfolineData` with method `getDispayInfoline($lang)` (class name Callcenter_View_Helper_InfolineData) and I pass this helper via controller to view.

Controller Code:

```
$this->view->openHours = $this->view->getHelper('infolineData')->getDispayInfoline($lang);
```

View Code:

```
{$openHours}
```

How can I make similar call using only Open Power Template?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find solution

```
$this->view->getHelper('infolineData')->getDispayInfoline($lang)
```

is equal to

```
{u:$view::getHelper('infolineData')::getDispayInfoline($view::language)}
```